# Criar um vetor com srand sem repetir números em C

Tags: c, array

Estou criando um vetor com números aleatórios de 1 a 60 usando a função rand. Esse vetor não pode conter números repetidos. Por exemplo, se o retorno do srand foi o numero 3, e já existe um número 3 no vetor, preciso gerar outro número aleatório e refazer a checagem. Porém estou com dúvida em como fazer essa repetição.

Por enquanto fiz isso:

```
    int vetor[30]={0};  //preciso de 30 valores aleatorios diferentes, aqui o vetor está cheio com zeros

    candidato = 1+rand()%59; //variavel que armazenará o valor a ser testado
```

Comment: Monte um array com os 60 números de 1 a 60, embaralhe esse array e pegue os 30 primeiros números, copiando-os para um outro array. O algoritmo de embaralhamento é o [Fisher-Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher–Yates_shuffle).

Comment: Perfeito! Muito mais otimizado do que criar vetores auxiliares ou percorrer para checar toda vez. Muito Obrigado @VictorStafusa

Answer (score -3):

Se baseie neste:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
int main() {
    int numero[50], i, j;
    char ja_consta;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i=0; i<50; i++) {
        numero[i] = rand() % 100 + 1;
        ja_consta = 'N';
        for (j=0; j<i && ja_consta == 'N'; j++) {
            if (numero[i] == numero[j])
                ja_consta = 'S';
        }
        if (ja_consta == 'S')
            i--;
    }
    for (i=0; i<50; i++)
        printf("\t%d", numero[i]);
    return 0;
}
```